# Estimate Shipping section is not retained after Update Basket

Tags: cart, magento-2.2.5, magento-upgrade, checkout-summary

I upgrade my Magento store from 2.1.7 to 2.2.5 and I faced an issue on cart page.

When adding a product to cart and go to **/checkout/cart/**, In shipping summary section update the **shipping country, postcode and state** 
[image]

and click on **Update Shopping Basket** then address is not retained to and comes in default country [image].

Can someone help me to get out of this?

Comment: Experiencing same in Magento version 2.3.1. Delivery Information does not persist when making actions to the cart e.g. update qty, remove item, add item. Currently unable to find potential solutions unless `$this->cart->save()` is removing the existing checkout postcode.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159363)

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing same in Magento version 2.3.1. Delivery Information does not persist when making actions to the cart e.g. update qty, remove item, add item.

The postcode/region/country values can be found in the `mage-cache-storage` key within Local Storage which can be found in the Developer Toolbar.
You can access the values needed through:
`mage-cache-storage.checkout-data.shippingAddressFromData` object or through `mage-cache-storage.cart-data.address` object

Note that when you update the Cart the `mage-cache-storage.checkout-data.shippingAddressFromData` no longer exists hence the values clearing.

I have used the following snippet within the shipping-estimation.js of the Magento_Checkout module to check if the postcode can be found in the `cart-data` if it doesn't exist in the `checkout-data` and populate the fields that way.

`$.initNamespaceStorage('mage-cache-storage').localStorage.get('cart-data.address.postcode')`

There may be better methods of getting this storage but this is what I've settled for at the moment. Unfortunately time does not currently permit me to find the "perfect" solution.